# Using Lodash _.map and Typescript to create new column for filtering

Tags: angularjs, typescript, lodash

In my controller I have code that filters just fine but i want to create a new field that concatenates two fields for an Angular filter in html.  This is what I have that doesn't work..  Is this possible?

```
            private filterByColumns: string = ""; 

            getData = (): void => {
                var vm = this;
                this.carHopService.getDetails({ id: this.$state.params["id"], type: this.$state.params["type"] }).then(
                    (data: any) => {
                        vm.primaryCarHopData = _.filter(data.carHopList, {
                            carHopType: "Primary"
                        });

--->                **vm.primaryCarHopData = _.map(data.carHopList, {
                            vm.filterByColumns=fullName + " " + age

                        });**
                    });
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how map works. In the callback function, you need to return something:

```
_.map([0,1,2], (x) => x + 1)
> [1,2,3]
// old syntax
_.map([0,1,2], function (x) { return x + 1 })
> [1,2,3]
```

You can simply replace `_.map` with `_.forEach` and you will have your mapped data in `data.carHopList`.

---

Clarification:

I'm not good with words so let me put here very simple implementations for both `forEach` and `map`:

```
// these functions do not mock lodash counterparts 100%
// as lodash fns can work with objects too
// and they have some shortcuts, see docs

function forEach(arr, callback) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    callback(arr[i], i);
  }
  return arr;
}

function map(arr, callback) {
  var newArr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    newArr[i] = callback(arr[i], i);
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

Comment: That last statement does not seem correct to me. Can you clarify it a little more? `_.forEach` is not a replacement for `_.map` unless you are mutating the source array.

Answer (score 0):

Someone had steered me in the direction of map.  What I ended up doing was using Angular by adding this to controller:

```
    filterTextByCols = (row) => {
        return (angular.lowercase(row.fullName).indexOf(angular.lowercase(this.filterQuery) || '') !== -1 ||
            angular.lowercase(row.birthDate).indexOf(angular.lowercase(this.filterQuery) || '') !== -1);
    }
```

And then using filterTextByCols in filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in vm.persons | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter: vm.filterTextByCols">
```